# Proving that the sequence $x_n = \frac{n+1}{3n-2}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

The definitions I've been given for Cauchy sequence are

1)$\forall \epsilon>0 ,\, \exists N \in\Bbb{N} \,$  $\ni $ $\forall n,m>N \ $ , it follows that $|x_m-x_n|<\epsilon$

2)$\forall \epsilon>0 ,\, \exists N \in\Bbb{N} \,$ $\ni $  $\forall n,>N \, p\in \Bbb{N} \ $ , it follows that $|x_n-x_{n+p}|<\epsilon$

So far I've worked out that for $m,n \in \Bbb{N}\,, |x_m-x_n| = |\frac{5(n-m)}{(3m-2)(3n-2)}|$, but I don't know how I can continue from there. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is $m$ in 2)?

Comment: Do you know the proof of the theorem - every convergent sequence is cauchy?

Comment: Note that $$
\left| {x_n  - x_m } \right| = \left| {\frac{5}{{3(3n - 2)}} - \frac{5}{{3(3m - 2)}}} \right| \le \left| {\frac{5}{{3(3n - 2)}}} \right| + \left| {\frac{5}{{3(3m - 2)}}} \right|.
$$ Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\frac{n+1}{3n-2}=\frac13+\frac53\cdot\frac{1}{3n-2}$